# How can I store range values to arrays and then unite them in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am relatively new in VBA and still not able to manipulate range and array values the way I want.

I am building a user form and I want to be able to combine the values from two ranges provided by the user in a single array in order to sort them and then use them to build a statistical test (Wilcoxon). I am struggling to do the first part. I have tried numerous alternations from different questions, but nothing seems to work.

Here is where I got so far:

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
    Dim range1 As Range
    Dim range2 As Range

    Dim k As Integer
    'Sample1 and 2 provided by the user
    Set range1 = Range(Sample1.Value)
    Set range2 = Range(Sample2.Value)

    n = Application.Count(range1)
    m = Application.Count(range2)

    Dim arr1() As Variant
    ReDim arr1(1 To n)
    Dim arr2() As Variant
    ReDim arr2(1 To m)
    Dim unionarr() As Variant
    ReDim unionarr(1 To n + m)
    Dim x As Variant
    'store the range values in two arrays
    arr1 = range1
    arr2 = range2
    'combine (unite) the two arrays in a new array
    For k = 1 To n
        unionarr(k) = arr1(k)
        Next k

    For k = n + 1 To n + m
        unionarr(n + k) = arr2(k)
        Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: use union on the ranges before you kick off, so range3=union(range1,range2)

Comment: could you give some more details. Ok I set range3 =union then? How do I assign the cell values from the range to the array? I want for example if the user selects a1:a5 and b1:b5 the unionarr(1) to be the number in cell a1, unionarr(2) to be the value in cell a2 and so on and so forth

Comment: Do the same, but you'll just have one range.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
    Dim range1 As Range
    Dim range2 As Range
    Dim vArr1 As Variant
    Dim vArr2 As Variant
    Dim vCombined() As Variant
    Dim lComb As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    'Sample1 and 2 provided by the user
    Set range1 = Range(Sample1.Value)
    Set range2 = Range(Sample2.Value)
    vArr1 = range1.Value2
    vArr2 = range2.Value2
    'Assuming same # of columns in both ranges!
    ReDim vCombined(LBound(vArr1, 1) To UBound(vArr1, 1) + UBound(vArr2, 1), LBound(vArr1, 2) To UBound(vArr1, 2))
    For lRow = LBound(vArr1, 1) To UBound(vArr1, 1)
        For lCol = LBound(vArr1, 2) To UBound(vArr1, 2)
            lComb = lComb + 1
            vCombined(lComb, lCol) = vArr1(lRow, lCol)
        Next
    Next
    For lRow = LBound(vArr2, 1) To UBound(vArr2, 1)
        For lCol = LBound(vArr2, 2) To UBound(vArr2, 2)
            lComb = lComb + 1
            vCombined(lComb, lCol) = vArr2(lRow, lCol)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim r3 As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim a() As Double
Dim iCounter As Integer

Set r1 = Range("a1:a10")
Set r2 = Range("c1:c10")

Set r3 = Union(r1, r2)

ReDim a(r3.Cells.Count)

iCounter = 0

For Each c In r3.Cells
    a(iCounter) = c.Value
    iCounter = iCounter + 1
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect and simple.